# Mail is not sending in cakephp 3.0

Tags: email, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I Have faced lots of error and now soo close that hole send function is executing then then redirect to anather page but the problem is mail is not sending. Any Idea, Thank you in advance

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controller;
    use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

    use App\Controller\AppController;
    use Cake\Mailer\Email;
    function send(){
    $name=$this->request->data('name');
            $receiver_email='adangwa111@gmail.com';
            $Subject_Title=$this->request->data('sub');
            $Sender_email=$this->request->data('yemail');

    $email = new Email();
    $email->template('invite', 'default')
        ->emailFormat('html')
        ->from('Amit@gmail.com')
        ->to('adangwa111@gmail.com')
        ->subject('About')

        ->send();
    $this->redirect(['controller'=>'Recommand','action' => 'index']);
    }
    }
```

And this is my App configuration

```
  'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Smtp',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'transport' => 'Smtp',
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'timeout' => 35,
            'username' => '*******@gmail.com',
            'password' => '********',
            'client' => null,

        ],
    ],
```

Comment: You should enable [less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) in gmail settings

Comment: I didn't find your controller name according to CakePHP Controller will you check it ?

Comment: thanku tarikul05 its jst code and paste went missing while posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this configuration in my App file

```
 'EmailTransport' => [
    'Smtp' => [
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
       'port' => 465,
        'timeout' => 35,
        'username' => '*******@gmail.com',
        'password' => '********',
        'from'=>'*******@gmail.com',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => null,
    ],
],

'Email' => [
    'default' => [ 
  'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from'=>'*******@gmail.com'
    ],
],
```

Please check if this works fine on your server as well. I also tried many combinations before getting this work.